# Radiant stove burner - Wire or switch?

Tags: electrical, kitchens, stove

One of the burners on my glass range stopped working. More specifically, it won't turn on when I turn the knob, but it does warm up when using the Simmer Select setting.

I lifted the glass cooktop to take a look and one of the connectors looks a bit brown. See picture.

Could that be the culprit, or is it more likely the switch?

[image: Stove burner connectors]

Comment: It is a touch dirty, but doubt if that is the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll order a new switch.

Answer (score -1):

I would replace that box with the wires going to the element if possible or it and the element if its connected and cannot be removed from the element.  It looks like it has overheated there at one time.  That box looks as if it is a resistor pack to allow the different stages of heat and that's why you're only getting low heat.

Comment: "a resistor pack to allow the different stages of heat"...? That's not how stove burner heat settings work.